# Help understanding the quaternion based Madgwick filter derivation

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers, vectors, quaternions

I am trying to understand the derivation process of Madgwicks fillter which can be found in this paper:
https://www.samba.org/tridge/UAV/madgwick_internal_report.pdf

Lets name the the above paper as paper $[1]$ in the future context of my question.

I have a normalised quaternion $^S_E\hat{q}$ defined as:

$$^S_E\hat{q}=q_1+q_2i+q_3j+q_4k$$

where $q_1$, $q_2$, $q_3$ and $q_4$ are real numbers and $i$, $j$ and $k$ are imaginary numbers. The conjugat of $^S_E\hat{q}$ is $^S_E\hat{q}^*$ and it is defined as:

$$^S_E\hat{q}^*=q_1-q_2i-q_3j-q_4k$$

I also have the quaternion $^E\hat{g}$ defined as:

$$^E\hat{g}=0+0i+0j+1k$$

as well as a quaternion $^S\hat{a}$ defined as:

$$^S\hat{a}=0+a_xi+a_yj+a_zk$$

where $a_x$, $a_y$, $a_z$ are real numbers. In paper $[1]$ function $f_g$ is defined as a multiplication of $^S_E\hat{q}^*$, $^E\hat{g}$ and $^S_E\hat{q}$ minus $^S\hat{a}$:

$$f_g=^S_E\hat{q}^*\cdot^E\hat{g}\cdot^S_E\hat{q}-^S\hat{a}$$

When I try to obtain the expresin for $f_g$ using the above equation I get:

$$f_g=0+(2(q_2q_4-q_1q_3)-a_x)i+(2(q_1q_2+q_3q_4)-a_y)j+(q_1^2-q_2^2-q_3^2+q_4^2-a_z)k$$

The problem is, in paper $[1]$ the expression for $f_g$ (which is shown in equation number $(25)$ of the paper) is:

$$f_g=0+(2(q_2q_4-q_1q_3)-a_x)i+(2(q_1q_2+q_3q_4)-a_y)j+(2(0.5-q_2^2-q_3^2)-a_z)k$$

As you can see, there is a difference between mine and the papers function $f_g$. Namely, the real part that is multiplied by the imaginary number $k$ is different. This is the problem I am facing. I tried doing the math three times and I always get the same result. Please help me find the mistake I am making. For starters, I need to know is paper $[1]$ wrong or am I wrong. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quaternion multiplication is known as [Hamilton product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Hamilton_product).  Let $\mathbf{q} = q_1 + q_2 \mathbf{i} + q_3 \mathbf{j} + q_4 \mathbf{k}$ and $\mathbf{s} = s_1 + s_2 \mathbf{i} + s_3 \mathbf{j} + s_4 \mathbf{k}$.  The product $\mathbf{q} \mathbf{s}$ is
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{q} \mathbf{s} & = ( q_1 s_1 - q_2 s_2 - q_3 s_3 - q_4 s_4 ) \\
~ & + ( q_1 s_2 + q_2 s_1 + q_3 s_4 - q_4 s_3 ) \mathbf{i} \\
~ & + ( q_1 s_3 - q_2 s_4 + q_3 s_1 + q_4 s_2 ) \mathbf{j} \\
~ & + ( q_1 s_4 + q_2 s_3 - q_3 s_2 + q_4 s_1 ) \mathbf{k} \\
\end{aligned}$$
as described in equation (4) in the linked PDF.

Given the above $\mathbf{q}$, $\mathbf{q}^* = q_1 - q_2 \mathbf{i} - q_3 \mathbf{j} - q_4 \mathbf{k}$, $\mathbf{b} = 1 \mathbf{k}$, and $\mathbf{a} = a_x \mathbf{i} + a_y \mathbf{j} + a_z \mathbf{k}$, then
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{q}^* \mathbf{b} \mathbf{q} - \mathbf{a} & = 0 \\
~ & + \bigl( 2 ( q_2 q_4 - q_1 q_3 ) - a_x \bigr) \mathbf{i} \\
~ & + \bigl( 2 ( q_1 q_2 + q_3 q_4 ) - a_y \bigr) \mathbf{j} \\
~ & + \bigl( q_1^2 - q_2^2 - q_3^2 + q_4^2 - a_z \bigr) \mathbf{k} \\
\end{aligned}$$
This matches your result, and is correct (verified with wxMaxima).

Because $\mathbf{q}$ describes an orientation (or rotation), it is an unit quaternion, for which $q_1^2 + q_2^2 + q_3^2 + q_4^2 = 1$.  This is mentioned in the PDF just before equation (1).

Thus,
$$\begin{aligned}
q_1^2 - q_2^2 - q_3^2 + q_4^2 - a_z & = q_1^2 + q_2^2 + q_3^2 + q_4^2 - 2 q_2^2 - 2 q_3^2 - a_z \\
~ & = 1 - 2 q_2^2 - 2 q_3^2 - a_z \\
~ & = 2 \left( \frac{1}{2} - q_2^2 - q_3^2 \right) - a_z \\
\end{aligned}$$
which means your solution and the solution shown in equation (25) in the PDF are equivalent, because $\mathbf{q}$ is an unit quaternion.

Comment: Hello Glärbo. Thank you very much for helping me. Now I understand completely how the filter works. I wish you the best in the future!